# Вставить символ на нужную позицию с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: javascript

Нужно вставить в определенное место строки символ, используя регулярные выражения.
У меня есть только символ для вставки и позиция на которую нужно его поставить. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: приведите пример

Comment: @GENESIS есть символ " * ", есть строка str="abcdef", мне нужно вставить * после "c", т.е. на 3-юю позицию

Comment: а если будет несколько `c`?

Comment: @Grundy, я ориентируюсь не та букву "c", в на ее позицию в строке, в данном случае - это 3

Comment: позиции с 1 начинаются?

Comment: с нуля, вставка после "c", у которой позиция 2, а значит новый символ после "c" будет стоять на позиции 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Вставлять" можно несколькими методами, например

1. разбить строку на подстроки, с помощью методов [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) или [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) и собрать новую строку:

   ```js
   function insert(str, symbol, index) {
     return str.substring(0, index) + symbol + str.substring(index);
   }
   console.log(insert("abcdef", '*', 3));
   ```
2. Использовать [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) с регулярным выражением

   ```js
   function insert(str, symbol, index) {
     return str.replace(new RegExp(`(.){${index}}`), `$&${symbol}`);
   }
   console.log(insert("abcdef", '*', 3));
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
$a = "abcdef";
$a = preg_replace("/c/", "$0*", $a);
echo $a;
?>
```

```js
console.log("abcdef".replace("c", "c*"));

if (!String.prototype.splice) { 
    String.prototype.splice = function(index, del, ...chars) {
      return this.slice(0, index) + chars.join('') + this.slice(index + Math.abs(del));
    };
  }

console.log('abcdef'.splice(3, 0, '*'));
```

Comment: на js чистый это как перевести?

Comment: ой прости щас сделаем

Comment: а можно сделать привязку не к символу, а к позиции, например к тройке?

Comment: теперь от позиции

Comment: спасибо, Вы меня спасли!)